# How to modify the query context when using a jQuery instance across iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery

For an existing webapp<sup>1</sup>, i am using a jQuery instance across iframes which causes me headaches.

jQuery is loaded (and aliased to $jq) in a Document which contains an iFrame(for a sidebar). In the iFrame document, I reuse the jQuery from the parent document by creating a new alias in the iFrame like `$jq = window.parent.$jq`.

The problem is now, that queries made in the iFrame refer to the Parent-Document, i.e. `$jq("body").attr("id")` yields the id of the body of the parent document not the id of the body of the iframe-document, so I would have to query with the context parameter like `$jq("body", document).attr("id")` to get the id of the document jQuery is currently being executed in.

My Question is: can I do anything, so I would not have to add the context parameter to every single query in order to scope the queries to the current document? For example, can I set the context globally for jQuery or such?

**Parent Document**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parent</title>
    <style>body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif;} #page{ display: flex; } #main { padding: 10px; flex: 1 0 auto; } #sidebar{ width: 360px; background-color: #fafafa; border: 0; padding: 10px; height: calc(100vh - 20px); } </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $jq = jQuery;
    </script>
</head>
<body id="Parent">
    <div id="page">
        <iframe id="sidebar" src="sidebar.html"></iframe>
    
        <div id="main">
            <h2>I am the parent</h2>
            <code class="result"></code>
        </main>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        $('.result').html('$jq("body").attr("id"): <b>' + $jq("body").attr("id") + '</b>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**iFrame Document** (sidebar.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sidebar</title>
    <style>body{font-family: sans-serif;}</style>
</head>
<body id="Sidebar">

    <h2>I am the sidebar iFrame</h2>
    <code class="result"></code>
    
    <script>
        var $jq = window.parent.$jq;
        var theId = $jq("body").attr("id");
        var theIdithContext = $jq("body", document).attr("id");
        var el = document.querySelector('code');
        el.innerHTML +=('$jq("body").attr("id"): <b>' + theId + '</b><br><br>');
        el.innerHTML +=('$jq("body", document).attr("id"): <b>' + theIdithContext + '</b>');
        
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

And here a [testcase](https://stefanseiz.com/jq-testcase/) outlining my problem.

---

<sup>1</sup> which happens to use jQuery and replacing that is out of scope for now

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: It's 2023, there's really *very* little that jQuery adds in the way to convenience compared to [native web APIs](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) these days. You should consider solving the problem by just not using jQuery at all.

Comment: @Quentin I would not know how to include the test case in the question itself, as the code snippets provide no way to create a document consisting of two files (which is needed for an iframe) thus, the link to the external test case.

Comment: @zıəsuɐɟəʇs — You've linked to Dropbox so it's not like it was a live demo in the first place. (That said, an externally linked live demo can be a useful **supplement** to an [mcve] expressed as code in the question itself, it's only a problem when used as a **replacement**).

Comment: @Quentin i have modified the link to show the tescase as a working example on my Webserver

Comment: Is there a reason why the page within the iframe can't get it's own copy of jQuery? ex. `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>`. BTW, it's optimal to load jQuery after the DOM has been rendered by placing `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @zer00ne I guess if you frequently load widgets in iframes, you do not want to load a jQuery instance into all of them, even if they happen to be hosted by someone else, to ease the load of the user's browser.

Comment: @LajosArpad I've never used a widget and haven't used more than one iframe per page either, besides jQuery loads once unless the `<script>` tag is loaded by AJAX. BTW, OP has a tag for JavaScript as well so I believe providing a non-jQuery answer is just as valid.

Comment: @zer00ne it was a thought-experiment. As about jQuery being loaded only once, I would not assume that all now existent or future browsers are and will behave like that.

Comment: @LajosArpad I have just replied to said *thought experiment* with fact. Sorry I just naturally assume that the de facto are modern browsers unless the OP specified otherwise.

Comment: @zer00ne The thought experiment is about someone using multiple widgets. Your answer was that you did not do so. That has no relevance in our discussion. As about assumptions, I would not assume anything. A code that does not unnecessarily instruct a page to load a resource due to assuming that it will not be loaded anyway is bogus. Let's just avoid writing unnecessary code rather than arguing they will not increase network load based on assumptions. Not writing unnecessary code is superior to writing unnecessary code and hoping for the best.

Comment: @LajosArpad OK, the "generic you", I'll give you that. BTW, I honestly just use what works -- what is deemed a necessity may become superfluous in the future. I'll leave it that since the last 7 comments are not productive.

Comment: My intention was to somehow save resources by only having one jQuery instance. Reading all the comments and answers makes me realize, that it is probably neglectable and I should just load jQuery again from within the document in the iFrame (so it gets its own instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer: it's impossible, a longer answer: it's not needed.

I think the whole problem is overengineered, too much perfection & DRY. you can easily reuse the parent's jQuery object to get your sidebar's body and work with it:

```
const $body = window.parent.$(document.body);
```

But why you need to include your script in the iframe? Also seems unnecessary. You can easily manipulate your iframe from the parent:

```
const $iframeBody = $($('iframe')[0].contentDocument.body);
$iframeBody.append("<div>added by parent</div>");
```

Also I consider using `$(selector)` everywhere as low quality jQuery spaghetti code since it's lacking any container context.

Back to the problem.

First if you look at jQuery's minified code you'll find it's a hard object which means the window & document become private scope variables defined at the script execution:

```
/*! jQuery v3.3.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
!function(e, t) {
    "use strict";
    "object" == typeof module && "object" == typeof module.exports ? module.exports = e.document ? t(e, !0) : function(e) {
        if (!e.document)
            throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
        return t(e)
    }
    : t(e)
}("undefined" != typeof window ? window : this, function(e, t) {
    "use strict";
    var n = []
      , r = e.document
      , i = Object.getPrototypeOf
      , o = n.slice
      , a = n.concat
      , s = n.push
      , u = n.indexOf
      , l = {}
      , c = l.toString
      , f = l.hasOwnProperty
      , p = f.toString
      , d = p.call(Object)
      , h = {}
```

So you can't change something like prototype to change window & document.

Second to create a jQuery object for your iframe you just need to execute this script again in your iframe. So the easiest why to put jQuery into your frame:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

Modern browsers are smart enough not to download the script twice.
So you have your jQuery in the parent page and in the iframe with one source code file. Basically the browser download the jQuery's source once than creates individual jQuery objects for your parent and iframe pages.
I think it's really easy and doesn't require any smarter solution.

The gist could be seen here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-ardinghelli-v7774q?file=/src/frame.js

In the iframe's JS I just easily can use both the parent's jQuery and the iframe's one:

```
$jp = window.parent.jQuery;
$(() => {
  $("body").append("<div>added by iframe</div>");
  $jp("body").append("<div>added by iframe</div>");
});
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: All unminified versions are available as well https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js (just remove `.min`)

Comment: @SalmanA it makes no difference, the result is the same in the end: window & document became a private scope's variables...

Comment: I meant you could copy from the unminified version in your answer. Yes it does not make any difference but function(e, t) is less readable than function (global, factory)

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexanderNenashev - I was trying to be nice and save resources and not have multiple jQuery instances. Probably not worth it, so I'll just give the iFrame its own jQuery instance by loading the src again.

Comment: @zıəsuɐɟəʇs you are welcome, adding multiple <script> is not a performance hit in your case :)

Comment: @zıəsuɐɟəʇs Thanks for reps, will be looking for your questions further, subscribed to your feed here

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function in `sidebar.html` that will work in the context you need.
And you can also not assign `$jq = jQuery;`.

In the code below, `jQuery` will have a Parent Document context and `$` will have an iFrame Document context. (You can assign any names to the variables).

```js
const jQuery = window.parent.$;
const $ = (selector) => jQuery(selector, document);
Object.setPrototypeOf( $, jQuery );
```

[**Example**](https://imhvost.github.io/76381438.html)

---

Parent Document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Parent</title>
  <style>body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif;} #page{ display: flex; }</style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="Parent">
  <div id="page">
    <iframe id="sidebar" src="sidebar.html"></iframe>
    <div id="main">
      <h2>I am the parent</h2>
      <code class="result"></code>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>$('.result').html(`bodyID: <b>${$('body').attr('id')}</b>`);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

iFrame Document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sidebar</title>
  <style>body{font-family: sans-serif;}</style>
</head>
<body id="Sidebar">
  <h2>I am the sidebar iFrame</h2>
  <code class="result"></code>
  <script>
    const jQuery = window.parent.$;
    const $ = (selector) => jQuery(selector, document);
    Object.setPrototypeOf( $, jQuery );
    const bodyID = $('body').attr('id');
    const parentBodyID = jQuery('body').attr('id');
    const el = document.querySelector('code');
    $('code').html(`bodyID: <b>${bodyID}</b><br>parentBodyID: <b>${parentBodyID}</b>`);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: jQuery function has different signatures e.g. `$("<input>", {type: "text"})`. You're forcing a specific signature (two arguments, second one is document element). That could cause problems unless the jQuery code (which you cannot control) is written in a specific way.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks for the comment. Yes, you are right, it should be considered.

Comment: Clever idea, thanks a lot! But thinking about implementing this so all jQuery chaining is also supported (i.e. `$jq(".test").first().html("<p>Nightmares</p>")`) etc. makes me think that I'll be better off, just not saving resources and giving the iFrame its own jq instance.

Comment: All chains work fine. In the [example](https://imhvost.github.io/76381438.html), I did this: `const bodyID = $('body').first().closest('html').find('body').attr('id');`. Here is the code at [github](https://github.com/imhvost/imhvost.github.io/blob/main/76381438-sidebar.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can define `$jq` as being a `function` that takes a `selector` as an attribute and calls `window.parent.$jq(selector, document)`:

```
        var $jq = function(selector) {
            return window.parent.$jq(selector, document);
        };
```

Full `iframe` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sidebar</title>
    <style>body{font-family: sans-serif;}</style>
</head>
<body id="Sidebar">

    <h2>I am the sidebar iFrame</h2>
    <code class="result"></code>
    
    <script>
        var $jq = function(selector) {
            return window.parent.$jq(selector, document);
        };
        var theId = $jq("body").attr("id");
        var theIdithContext = $jq("body", document).attr("id");
        var el = document.querySelector('code');
        el.innerHTML +=('$jq("body").attr("id"): <b>' + theId + '</b><br><br>');
        el.innerHTML +=('$jq("body", document).attr("id"): <b>' + theIdithContext + '</b>');
        
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Successful test:

[image]

Comment: I would like to know what the reason for the down-vote was, so, if there is a good reason to down-vote this answer, then I would know what needs to be improved.